# Scalar-Valued Function with Parameters and output is null but iam expecting sum(marks)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Function:

```
create function fn_with_parameter
(
    @id int=null
)
returns int
with returns null on null input 
as
  begin 
    declare @total int
    select @total=sum(marks) from test3
    where id=@id
    return @total
  end
```

Select:

```
select dbo.fn_with_parameter(default);
```

Comment: could you elaborate your question? just copy/paste the code cannot be enough to SO community help you.

Comment: `with returns null on null input `, `@id int=null`, `dbo.fn_with_parameter(default)` - ???

Comment: @PareshJ code is ok..but output is null

Comment: @j.mani : Modified code. Please check now.

Comment: tanx its working @PareshJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your function as :

```
create function fn_with_parameter
(
@id int=null
)
returns int
--with returns null on null input 
as
begin 
declare @total int=0
if isnull(@id,'') = ''
set @id = ''

select @total=sum(marks) from test3
where isnull(id,'')=@id
return isnull(@total,0)
end

select dbo.fn_with_parameter(default);
```